# Simple SQL query not using index with order clause and larger limit MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, mariadb

I just came across an issue with database not taking in account index when selecting larger amount of data.

It's a simple select with order clause.

This query (or any other with limit less then a million)

```
SELECT * 
FROM mon_stat_detail 
WHERE 1 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 500000
```

properly uses an index on column id (btw. its not primary but unique index)

[image]

While this query

```
SELECT *
FROM mon_stat_detail 
WHERE 1 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1000000
```

is using file sort.

[image]

Table is quite large, it has about 60 mil. records.

With file sort it takes 15 minutes and creates over 20GB of data on disk due to filesort

However if I force index on the same query

```
SELECT * 
FROM mon_stat_detail FORCE INDEX (id_2) 
WHERE 1 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1000000
```

it is using it and takes just seconds as expected.

[image]

Any idea why is this happening? Why do I need to force this index on such a simple query?

(pared down schema:)

```
CREATE TABLE mon_stat_detail (
    id int(16) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    sensor_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    time datetime NOT NULL, 
    … other about 10 columns ... 
    PRIMARY KEY (sensor_id,time), 
    UNIQUE KEY id_2 (id), 
    … some more indexes and FK …
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=550579790 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Database:

- Server version: 10.1.48-MariaDB-0+deb9u2 - Debian 9.13
- Protocol version: 10

Comment: There exists a percent of selected rows in optimizer settings which affects. If the percent of selected rows is above this value then server assumes that table scan is more effective then index scan. But I do not recommend to adjust optimizer settings which affects all queries - forcing the index usage is more safe solution.

Comment: hm.. in our case it would need to be set to 1.5% which would be quite too low. do you know exactly which option is it?

Comment: No, I never adjust default settings (no need), and. of course, I don't remember. See, for example, [The Optimizer Cost Model](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cost-model.html).

Comment: There is no setting (that I know of) to control that cutoff.  Also, MariaDB 10.1 may not be using the "cost model" mentioned in Akina's link.  As MySQL was implementing the "cost model" code, MariaDB was taking the Optimizer in other directions.  Still, both products pick between table scan versus bouncing between the index's BTree and the data's BTree.

Comment: It's rather rare to ask for a million rows; what will the client do with such a mass of data?

Comment: @RickJames This is a made up query to investigate what is going on. The issue appeared in automated job that is using mysqldump to export last million rows from large monitoring data set. it is then imported to another database for testing. 1 million may look a lot at first glance but it's really not, just few days of data actually. Another  problem is also that I didn't yet figure out how to force index when where clause is used with mysqldump. But I'd rather understand why this is happening. that index should be taken without knowing any statistics. as this is primitive select.

Comment: If your sample query has only one column, it is _not_ representative of your real query.  You _must_ have the same indexes (including the PK) and at least one extra column (assuming the query is `SELECT * ...`).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. the query explain is run on same table as mysqldump is doing it. it's just that mysqldump can take only where part. but it selects all columns by nature. so using SELECT * ... query basically is exactly same query as mysqldump builds up and is using. I can observe same behaviour with query explain and with dump. just that explain is telling me what it would do and bump is really doing it.

Comment: @Stan - Caution:  The table is one-eighth of the way to overflowing `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: @Stan - Based on "Columns:", there is only one column, namely `id`.  Hence, `SELECT *` would be fetching that one column.  Meanwhile, the fact that the `PRIMARY KEY` of the _real_ table is something other than `(id)` could influence the conclusion.  I am removing that misleading, old, info.

Comment: @RickJames thanks for pointing out the auto increment owerflow ;o)

Answer (score 0):

- If the goal is to fetch *any* million rows, leave out the `ORDER BY`.
- If the goal is to fetch the *last* million rows *and* there are no gaps in `id`, then use

  ```
    WHERE id > (SELECT MAX(id) FROM mon_stat_detail) - 1000000
    ORDER BY id  ASC    -- note; and no LIMIT is needed
  ```
- If there might be gaps, you could see if running this (before the Select) helps:

  ```
    ANALYZE TABLE mon_stat_detail;
  ```

For InnoDB it is fast and it refreshes the "statistics" on which the query plan is based.

Comment: Thanks Rick. This worked as work around to prevent file sort. I still would like to know why is this happening. But If noone answers I'll accept your answer. Thnak you.

Comment: @Stan - Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It sounds like `id ` is not the `PRIMARY KEY`, and that would help answer your question.  Also, it may lead to a more reliable way to achieve your goal.

Comment: I mentioned that in description of the issue. the Id has unique index on it. Primary key is sensor_id+date   as this is how the messages are being processed. still if id has a unique key and it is used in ORDER BY .. without any WHERE condition. I can't see a reason why it is not used for select with LIMIT. btw. the CREATE TABLE statement is too long for limit here. and didn't really find a way how to send you PM.

Comment: Cut down version of create table 
CREATE TABLE `mon_stat_detail` (
  `id` int(16) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sensor_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
… other about 10 columns ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`sensor_id`,`time`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_2` (`id`),
… some more indexes and FK …
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=550579790 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: @Stan - Thanks for the "cut down create"; that is enough.  I am stumped.

Comment: I still can't mark this answer as correct. Work around is not good enough, as some data from this table is being deleted when not needed. It created many gaps in ID sequence. So selecting by ID > instead of limit does export many rows less and its basically random in number of resulting records. I'll go for adding one more index on time column and use where with limiting time of lets say one week and add limit then. This may work well. I'll try to point out this issue to MariaDB devs attention to see if this is something to report as bug.